# How to pass parameters to the route in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm exploring Angular. I'm trying some basic concepts like routing, Observables (and subscribing to them), making HTTP requests and routing parameters. I've created a very basic scenario where I'm making a HTTP GET request to JSONPlaceholder to fetch all albums. I've created a service for this. I've added:

```
<a [routerLink]="['albums', album.id]">{{album.title}}</a>
```

to album title, when I click on a title I should be routed to the detail view of that particular album. I'll show you my code also, but I think a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czmhca) will be more meaningful. Here's the code:

**album-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AlbumService } from './albums.service';
import { IAlbum } from './album';

@Component({
  template: './album-detail.component.html'
})
export class AlbumDetailComponent {

  album: IAlbum;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _albumService: AlbumService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id=+this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log("called for: "+id);
    this.getAlbumById(id);
  }

  getAlbumById(id: number) {
    this._albumService.getAlbumById(id).subscribe({
      next: album => this.onAlbumRetrieved(album)
    })
  }

  onAlbumRetrieved(album: IAlbum): void {
    this.album = album;
  }
}
```

**album.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AlbumListComponent } from './albums-list.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AlbumDetailComponent } from './album-detail.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: 'albums', component: AlbumListComponent},
      {path: 'albums/:id', component: AlbumDetailComponent},
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AlbumListComponent,
    AlbumDetailComponent
  ]
})
export class AlbumModule { }
```

My get request is also successful but there's something wrong with my routing:

[image: Screenshot of Mozilla DevTools with errors]

Comment: You're not referencing your child module in your app.module. Are you trying to lazy load the album module?

Comment: Lazy loading is my next milestone, but not now.  :-)
I've imported `AlbumModule` in `app.module.ts`. Is that what you're asking. Please correct me if I failed to understand.

Comment: The routing in your app module doesn't know anything about the album routing - you need to wire it up somehow. You can achieve this with lazy loading, or you can define the album routes in app module.

Comment: I'm following a lecture by Deborah Kurata on Pluralsight. This is not exactly her code but I tried following what she said. Here's the video: https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=3ed6cc4c-3620-4ee2-bd0b-fd5c63b7a0db

Comment: then if you don't want to make it lazy load, you have to register it in `app.module` , importing `AlbumModule` does not mean your routes will be registered to your root module.

Comment: @JohnVelasquez, I'm sorry I didn't understand your answer very well. Can you please show how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AppModule` doesn't have the album routes registered. Importing `AlbumModule` doesn't register the routes that you have attempted to register in there.

You can either handle the album routes by:

1. Delegate responsibility for the album routing by lazy loading the module.
2. Register album routing in your app module

Lazy loading is overkill for the purposes of this answer, and you can read up on that separately.

The simple solution here is to move the routes from `AlbumModule` into `AppModule`:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'albums', component: AlbumListComponent},
  {path: 'albums/:id', component: AlbumDetailComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
])
```

You should make the router link absolute (rather than relative to the current route) by prefixing it with a slash:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/albums', album.id]">{{album.title}}</a>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyq5wb

Note that I have also updated `AlbumDetailComponent`:

`templateUrl: './album-detail.component.html'`.

Comment: I'm such a silly person. Sorry for bothering you. I'll keep these in mind always.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 changes:

In **album-detail.component.ts**:

`templateUrl: './album-detail.component.html'`

In **album-list.component.html**:

`<a [routerLink]="[album.id]">{{album.title}}</a>`

Comment: I tried this @Benny, but it is not working. And I thing it should be `<a [routerLink]="['albums', album.id]">{{album.title}}</a>`

Comment: I made these changes in your https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czmhca and it worked

Comment: You've pasted my stackblitz link here. Can you please paste yours ?

Comment: I made the changes on yours, but here is a fork with the changes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szujbx

Answer (score 1):

you have to do only these changes.

in album.module.ts

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: 'albums', component: AlbumListComponent},
    {path: 'albums/album/:id', component: AlbumDetailComponent},
 ])
```

in album-detail.component.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './album-detail.component.html'
})
```

check updated code of these two files.

album.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AlbumListComponent } from './albums-list.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AlbumDetailComponent } from './album-detail.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: 'albums', component: AlbumListComponent},
      {path: 'albums/album/:id', component: AlbumDetailComponent},
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AlbumListComponent,
    AlbumDetailComponent
  ]
})
export class AlbumModule { }
```

album-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AlbumService } from './albums.service';
import { IAlbum } from './album';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './album-detail.component.html'
})
export class AlbumDetailComponent {

  album: IAlbum;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _albumService: AlbumService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id=+this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log("called for: "+id);
    this.getAlbumById(id);
  }

  getAlbumById(id: number) {
    this._albumService.getAlbumById(id).subscribe({
      next: album => this.onAlbumRetrieved(album)
    })
  }

  onAlbumRetrieved(album: IAlbum): void {
    this.album = album;
  }
}
```

let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Hi Piyush, actually `path: 'albums/album/:id'` isn't required at all. But thanks for the answer. I appreciate this.